# Can't add time to my X axis on my Plotly chart

Tags: python, plotly

I'm creating a Dash webapp where i have a real-time plotly chart. This chart gets updated every second. I would like to add to my X axis time instead of a fixed value. I tried setting `tickvals=` to `dt.now` but it doesn't work, since `tickvals` needs an array. Any advice?

```
 def gen_wind_speed(interval):

        trace = Scatter(
            y=df['num'],
            line=Line(
                color='#42C4F7'

            ),
        )

        layout = Layout(
            height=450,
            xaxis=dict(
                showgrid=False,
                showline=False,
                zeroline=False,
                fixedrange=True,
                tickvals= dt.now 

            ),

            margin=Margin(
                t=45,
                l=50,
                r=50
            )
        )

        return Figure(data=[trace], layout=layout)
```